# Is there a way to handle SQLExceptions that are generated by SqlDataSource

Tags: vb.net, timeout, sqlexception

I have been experiencing a problem with one of my vb applications where it is crashing at a certain time of day. In my code, there are only 4 places where that could be the cause of the crash. Three of them are from SQLDataSource queries and the other is in the code behind. I am pretty sure that I don't have a problem with the code behind as I have a using block in place. Further more, inside of that block I have a try catch finally where in the finally I am Disposing the command as well as the connection and Closing the connection. I have been reading some articles that tell me that I should use a SqlDataSource "selected" event to close the connection. I gave that a try but didn't have any success. This is the error that I am receiving:

> SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

This makes me feel like the "selected" event is not having a chance to get fired. So I thought I should try the "selecting" event. In it, I am trying to grab the connection string and close it. But I am not quite sure I am going down the correct path because I have been unable to catch exceptions inside of that event. Can someone out there please give me a hand with this issue I am facing?

Edit:
This is an example of how I am trying to use the selected event to close the connection

```
If Not IsNothing(e.Exception) Then
        Debug.Print("Exeception encounted while selecting for sqlData")
End If

e.ExceptionHandled = True
```

And here is and example of how I am trying to use the selecting event (I cannot figure out if an exception has been thrown here).

```
 Dim sqlDataConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("MYConnectionString")
 
 sqlDataConn.Dispose()
```

Comment: your best bet is to post code here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to intercept `SqlException` you need to use explicit "`using`", i.e. `try/catch`. Then, you can determine specific issue by the `Number` property.

```vb
try


catch ex as SqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Number)
    if ex.Number = xxx then
        ' do something
    end if
catch ex as Exception

finally

end try
```

if the question about handling this

```vb
If Not IsNothing(e.Exception) Then
    Debug.Print("Exeception encounted while selecting for sqlData")
End If
```

you can check the exception type

```vb
If e.Exception IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf e.Exception Is SqlException Then
.....
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, this only happens once a day. I will give this a try in both the "selecting" and "selected" events and let you know of my results.

Comment: I gave it a try and neither of the select events were reached. I know this because I have code that writes to a file at the start of the catch in both the selecting and selected events. Not quite sure where to go from here. Can you please provide some other suggestions? Is the way that I am checking for exception throwing me off (Not IsNothing(e.Exception) vs e.Exception IsNot Nothing)?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you did a breakpoint and found the query that was having this issue. The timeout issue is when a long-running query kills itself because it ran past the default timeout period.

A quick and dirty solution could be to just use a larger timeout in the connection strings you use, but long running queries can usually be a bad sign of an unoptimized query and should be addressed before your database grows any larger.

Comment: Timeout setting in the connection string is set as the connection's timeout. Query timeout should be set in the CommandTimeout property of the SQLCommand

Comment: Thanks. I was under the assumption that if there was one query like this, there might be more.

Comment: When the query kills itself, should I expect it to go the onselected event? I am considering increasing the CommandTimeout but I don't just want to put a bandage on the problem. Do you have any other suggestions that I could possibly try?